# The URL is not being matched/found: django

Tags: django

In my urls.py, i have this entry:

```
url(r'^get-advice/(?P<groupid>[0-9]+)/(?P<catid>[0-9]+)/(?P<style>[a-zA-Z]{6,11})/(?P<zone>[0-9]+)/$', views.give_insight, name='get-advice'),
```

I was hoping this would work:

http://localhost:9000/tips/get-adivce/6/1/sqare/1200

http://localhost:9000/land/get-adivce/6/1/sqare/1

http://localhost:9000/land/get-adivce/6/1/sqare/13

But nothing is being matched. The following works fine:

http://localhost:9000/tips/view-tips/6/1/

for url:

```
url(r'^view-tips/(?P<groupid>[0-9]+)/(?P<catid>[0-9]+)/$', views.give_insight, name='view-tips'),
```

Comment: `get-adivce` != `get-advice`

Answer (score 5):

The style group (`(?P<style>[a-zA-Z]{6,11})`) matches 6 to 11 characters, `sqare` only has 5 so it does not match.

Either you meant `square` either you need to change the character count.

Also you have a typo in the URLs you show: `get-adivce` -> `get-advice`

Comment: the square was a typo but the get advice part is correct. thanks guys.